# How to concat files with rollup?

Tags: rollup

I have the following files:

```
// a.js
var g = {
    version: 1,
    extend: function(source, target) {
        console.log('in g.extend');
    }
};

// b.js
g.extend(g, {
    h: function() {
        console.log('in h');
    }
});

// index.js
import './a';
import './b';
```

The result of building(as iife):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var g$1 = {
        version: 1,
        extend: function(source, target) {
            console.log('in g.extend');
        }
    };

    g.extend(g, {
        h: function() {
            console.log('in h');
        }
    });

}());
```

Rollup rename the `g` variable to `g$1`.

How can I prevent this ?

And is this the correct way to concat files ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Don't know why do you need to concat those files but the approach I would always follow is to use import/export statements:

```
// a.js
export const g = {
    version: 1,
    extend: function(source, target) {
        console.log('in g.extend');
    }
};

// b.js
import {g} from './a';
    g.extend(g, {
       h: function() {
            console.log('in h');
       }
});

// index.js
import './b';
```